# Android Retrofit : TypedByteArray instead of TypedFile is not working.

Tags: android, retrofit, multipart

I am using a multi-part request(POST) to send 3 images to the server. My method definition is below

```
@Multipart
@POST("/" + ENDPOINT_POST_PICTURE_SET)
SendPictureSetResponse sendPictureSet(@Part("image_1") TypedFile photo1, 
@Part("image_2") TypedFile photo2, @Part("image_3") TypedFile photo3,
@Part("string1") TypedString string1, @Part("string2") TypedString string2);
```

I have decided to compress these jpeg images to maybe 90% quality(maybe even 70%) before I attach them.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(application.getImageFilePaths().get(0));
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, byteArrayOutputStream);
```

I updated the method to take in three TypedByteArrays instead using the following code.

```
@Multipart
@POST("/" + ENDPOINT_POST_PICTURE_SET)
SendPictureSetResponse sendPictureSet(@Part("image_1") TypedByteArray photo1, 
@Part("image_2") TypedByteArray photo2, @Part("image_3") TypedByteArray photo3,
@Part("string1") TypedString string1, @Part("string2") TypedString string2);
```

I create the bytearrays as shown below and passed it to the method .

```
byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
```

The server however does not recognize this format. What changes do I need to make in my request(or/and in the server) for the server to accept this request format. Do I need to add a different mime type or header or is my request in it's entirety wrong? I am only adding an authorization header(token) for now, using a request interceptor.

Comment: did you find how to trick the server into accepting the typefile and typedbytearray at the same time ? thx